# Authorization error (Required permission)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I try to create an event from sheets to Google calendar which works fine when I use it through the menu, but when I try to trigger it using a OnEdit function it shows an authorization error.

> Exception: The script doesn't have permission to perform that action. Required permission:(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar || >https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly ||
> https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds)

My oauthScopes

```
      "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
      ],
```

The code I try to run:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  overwright(e);
}

function overwright(e) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    if( spreadsheet.getRange("Z3").getValue() == true ) {

      Inboeken ();

      spreadsheet.getRange('Z3').activate();
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('FALSE');
    }
  }

function Inboeken() {

  // Calendar info
  var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("email");
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //details
  var titel = "R'DAM - " + spreadsheet.getRange("I3").getValue() + " " + spreadsheet.getRange("M3").getValue();
  var startTime = spreadsheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var endTime = spreadsheet.getRange("C3").getValue();

  //discription
  var naam = spreadsheet.getRange("G3").getValue();
  var starttijd = spreadsheet.getRange("E3").getDisplayValues();
  var eindtijd = spreadsheet.getRange("F3").getDisplayValues();
  var aantal = spreadsheet.getRange("H3").getValue();
  var status = spreadsheet.getRange("K3").getValue();
  var notitiedatum = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd-MM-yyyy")

      console.log(naam + " " + startTime + " " + endTime + " " + aantal + " " + status + " " + notitiedatum);

event.createEvent(titel, startTime, endTime,
{ 
    description: 
    ("Naam: ".bold() + naam + "\n"
    +"Tijd: ".bold() + starttijd + " - " + eindtijd + "\n"
    + "Aantal: ".bold() + aantal + "\n" 
    + "\n"
    + "---"+"\n"
    + notitiedatum + " M: Als " + status + " ingeboekt"
   )
   , location: (naam + " / " + aantal + "  pax" ) 
    })
}
```

I found some information: [How to get permission to perform action in calendar google in spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643962/how-to-get-permission-to-perform-action-in-calendar-google-in-spreadsheet) but still have no clue if there is a solution or not? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: onEdit are simple triggers and cannot perform operations that require permission.

Comment: Can you run `Inboeken` from the script editor without disturbing any thing? When you do  that it will ask for permission and then the permissions are set for future runs including onEdit().

Comment: You need installable trigger `onEdit`. Check the linked duplicate.

Comment: To be clear, there is a solution.